# How to create a conditional handler/button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on an e-commerce website, and I'm trying to create a button/handler that only appears when the current date is less than or equal to 30 days from the deliveryAt. I tried doing this by placing my handler within an if/else statement, but it doesn't seem like I did this correctly since I'm getting a warning saying that I'm missing my `addToDevolucionHandler`. I would really appreciate any help or guidance on how to properly do this.
Thank you!

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listOrderMine, detailsOrder } from '../actions/orderActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import {createReturn } from '../actions/returnActions';
//import  {orderItems} from '../screens/OrderScreen';
import { RETURN_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/returnConstants';

export default function OrderHistoryScreen(props) {
  const order = useSelector((state) => state.order);
  const returnCreate = useSelector((state) => state.returnCreate);
  const {success, returned } = returnCreate;
  
  const orderMineList = useSelector((state) => state.orderMineList);
  const { loading, error, orders } = orderMineList;
  console.log({orders});
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listOrderMine());

  }, [dispatch]);
  
  
  const created = new Date('createdAt');
  const today = new Date();
  
  const thirtyDays = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  
  const timeDiff = today.getTime() - created.getTime();
  
  if(timeDiff <= thirtyDays){
    const addToDevolucionHandler = (orderId) => {
      props.history.push(`/make-return/${orderId}`);
  }
}
  else{
      console.log('Date is older than 30 days');
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Order History</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>DELIVERED</th>
              <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {orders.map((order) => (
              <tr key={order._id}>
                <td>{order._id}</td>
                <td>
                  {order.isDelivered
                    ? order.deliveredAt.substring(0, 10)
                    : 'No'}
                </td>
                
                <td>
                <button
                  onClick={()=>addToDevolucionHandler(order._id)}
                  className="primary block"
                   >
                  Make a Return
                 </button>
                </td>
             
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the `addToDevolucionHandler` is only visible in the `if` scope, and not visible at the outer scope at `return`.

You can modify it by creating the function in the outer layer like this:

```
const addToDevolucionHandler = (orderId) => {
  if(timeDiff <= thirtyDays){
    props.history.push(`/make-return/${orderId}`);
  }
  else{
      console.log('Date is older than 30 days');
  } 
  }
```

This way, the function is always created in the body of the functional component, you handle the `if` condition within the `addToDevolucionHandler` function.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you! Question: If instead of ```console.log ('Date is older than 30 days');``` I want the handler to disappear, do you know how I would do that?

Comment: @Gigi101 What do you mean "handler to disappear"? do you mean you want to hide the "Make a return" button? Then you can use a condition for rendering the button, so that the button don't show. Or you mean you don't want to define the handler function? The function itself is doing nothing if `timeDiff > thirtyDays` anyways so it's fine to define the function.